# Fetching webkit-transform of an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the -webkit-transform value of an image on my page.

When I inspect the element, I see the following:

```
<img src="https://camera.JPG" style="-webkit-transform: rotate(270deg); height: 337px; margin-left: -131px;" class="753 rotated_odd">
```

You can see that the image clearly has a rotation being applied to it.

However, when I attempt to fetch the webkit-transform with the following (where image is $('img.753'):

```
$(image).css('-webkit-transform')
```

I get the value "none"

**What's going on?**

Additionally, I tried the following:

```
style = window.getComputedStyle($(image).get(0));
matrix = new WebKitCSSMatrix(style.webkitTrans);
```

But I get 0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $(image).get(0)===image; you also don't need the -webkit- prefix for even semi-recent webkit browsers.

Comment: Try `var img = $("img").get(0);
var imgTransform = img.style.webkitTransform;
console.log(imgTransform);`

Comment: @guest271314 - your suggestion works for me, but I need to return a matrix, not the rotation value.  do you know how to do this?

Comment: ok, I determined what the issue was.  The image was in a bootstrap carousel, and the image was not active, so it wasn't able to fetch the transform.

Answer (score 0):

Your image variable is supposed to be

```
$('img.753')
```

and not

```
$('.img.753')
```

Comment: whoops, that was a typo